# Common practice for using Android themes dealing with versions

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

As I understand, preserving native look and feel is the recommended practice on android, but I can't help but notice that the default components compiled are not displayed as Holo on Jellybean. Does this mean that we must specify Holo in the version 11 folder styles.xml and have defaul elsewhere? It just seems counterintuitive to specify a custom theme to achieve a native experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When coding for multiple platform versions, you do need to specify a theme.

Under `res/values/styles.xml`, you should have something like:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black" />
</resources>
```

And then in `res/values-v11/styles.xml`

```
<resources>  
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
</resources>
```

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml, you should specify the theme as:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

However, if you don't specify any theme at all (so no `android:theme` attribute), Android should automatically go to the device's default theme.

Comment: Thanks A C, "coding for multiple app versions" I'm assuming you meant the version of Android device. If that were the case why would I ever need to specify 2 different themes (just not specify at all like you mentioned for all cases)

Comment: @Mike thanks for catching that error! Usually you do it if you're customizing your theme. Eg, if you want a light theme, the Device default might *not* be light, so you need a way to ensure.